# Using Jmeter to fill out a form?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

Can anyone help me figure out how to use jmeter and force it to fill out and submit a form automatically?  For example, I need to fill out the google search box and then click the I'm Feeling Lucky button?

Comment: Since Google uses GET and not POST, you cannot pass the search string as params. You will have to use the URL as the path in the HTTP request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google is not a good example because it uses GET for the form. For example, to search "jmeter" and press Feeling Lucky button, you can just send this URL,

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=jmeter&oq=&btnI=1

To do a real post, you need to find the form control field names from a trace or by looking at HTML source and just do something like showed here. The username/password are the field name to post. The action is http://www.example.com/login.

[image: JMeter example]

Comment: thanks this is awesome. You are right after looking at it with Fiddler, google only does GET requests...I was confused when I first saw it.

Answer (score 6):

Please note the screen shot is wrong.  The method is a "GET" and it should be set to "POST", otherwise the form will not be submitted properly.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you want to load test Google? If you just want to have a script that tests the functionality of a Website, try selenium: http://seleniumhq.org/. If you are actually trying to load test a form, you have to create the appropriate request. Using a tool like Fiddler can help.

Comment: I used google as an example since its similar to the form I am looking to test.